# CHANGE SERVER NAME IN SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me to change the server name in sql server 2008 please.

In this picture you see the server called SERVIDOR1

[image]

And if you query select @@servername you see the name I want. How can I change the first one ?

[image]

Why are they differents? I need to change the first name you see in first pic

Thanks so much

Comment: Don't shout in the title please.

Comment: `SERVIDOR1` which is your Local Machine Name & `SQLEXPRESS` is your SQL Server Instance Name which is indirectly display as `select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename`

Comment: Why do you want to rename your server?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different SQL Server instances, one is `default instance`, you see it as `SERVIDOR1` (that is your host name), the second is `named instance`: `SERVIDOR1\SQLEXPRESS`.

You cannot change the name of default instance as well as you cannot have 2 default instances on 1 pc, so if you want to get rid of the first instance you can uninstall it.

You can see both instances in the `Configuration Manager` or in Windows `Services`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much